# Get Stream of Child list from a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a SeniorEmployee class which has some attributes and under the same I have JuniorEmployee list. Now my criteria is to iterate in SeniorEmployee though streams and based on some criteria and then for the SeniorEmployee matching with the filter criteria we need to iterate in the juniorEmployee list and calculate their total salary. So, how can I do it in a single lambda expression though stream? Please help.

SeniorEmployee id filter criteria is if EmpCode is 10;

```
    SeniorEmployee{
    empCode;
    List<JuniorEmployee> junEmpList
    }

    JuniorEmployee{
     Emp Id;
    Salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seniors.stream().filter(x -> YOUR_SENIOR_CONDITION).mapToInt(x -> x.junEmpList.stream().mapToInt(y -> y.salary).sum()).sum()
```

or per your suggestion, try this:

```
seniors.stream().filter(x -> YOUR_SENIOR_CONDITION).flatMap(z -> z.junEmpList.stream()).mapToInt(o -> o.salary).sum();
```

Comment: Can we do it with reduce?
I found a solution where after first filter I am using flatMap to get the second List and then iside flatMap create another stream of JuniorEmp?

Comment: check my edited answer. If it works for you, please mark answer as correct.